# Memory leak detection tool for qt applications on windows

Tags: c++, windows, memory-leaks, qt4

Is there any free memory leak detection tool for QT programs to run on windows? I am using QtCreator as my IDE. If any plugin or add-on is available with QtCreator its best also.

Has anybody any idea about this?

Comment: Haven't seen such plugins for QT but you could use stand-alone tools as an option.

Comment: Use Fluid Memory Manager, works very well and can be easily integrated into your source tree. www.fluidstudios.com

Comment: Could you find any answer to your question?

Answer (score 1):

You may try [cppcheck](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/cppcheck/index.php) - it's a static analysis tool and is able to catch some leaks.

Answer (score 0):

maybe in your case would fit any addition, plug-in. you can try to use something like deleaker